# Hiding the links unless on a small screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, display

I am trying to create my header using bootstrap so that when it is in anything larger than small screen all that shows up is the brand and the links do not display, but when the screen is in small there is the collapsible button.

My site is @:
https://jspurling22.github.io/coursera-test/module3-sol/index.html

```
<div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse d-block d-sm-none">
    <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
        <li class="link-button">
            <a href="#chicken">Chicken</a>
        </li>
        <li class="link-button">
            <a href="#beef">Beef</a>
        </li>
        <li class="link-button">
            <a href="#sushi">Sushi</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I added the d-block d-sm-none and tried it in the div and the ul spots but nothing is working for me.
Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to show code here, and you need to show evidence of research or effort.

Comment: I will hint that the docs cover this pretty well, though. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

Comment: @isherwood I have tried for days, looking at the bootstrap documentation. Reading other sites and still have not figured it out. I understand I need to put the d-block and d-sm-none classes but when I put those classes anywhere it seems it doesn't do anything. I figured out that if i do a media query and use the visibility: hidden CSS it does what I want it to do, but besides that, I cannot figure out how to use bootstrap to do it.

Comment: Part of the problem may be that you're asking about Bootstrap 4 but loading Bootstrap 3 in your site. Pick one.

Answer (score 0):

First off the problem was that I was using Bootstrap 3 and calling Bootstrap 4. Changed to bootstrap 4, added .navbar-expand-xs like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xs navbar-dark bg-dark">
```

and added .d-block and .d-sm-none to the button

```
 <button class="navbar-toggler d-block d-sm-none" type="button" data- 
 toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria- 
 controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle 
 navigation">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question probably you should use the class `navbar-expand-[sm-md-lg]` which is all you need to hide the links.

`<div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-expand-sm"> </div>`

I also recommend upgrading to bootstrap 4 since bootstrap 5 is already up.

Do please let me know if that didn't help.